# I am trying to use websockets in my project. I have an error as follows

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4000/graphql' failed:
SubscriptionClient.connect @ client.ts:557
(anonymous) @ client.ts:522

My server is as follows,

```
import express from "express";
import { ApolloServer } from "@apollo/server";
import { expressMiddleware } from "@apollo/server/express4";
import { createServer } from "http";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
// import sequelize from "./db.js";
import { getAuthUser } from "./utils.js";
import typeDefs from "./schema.js";
import resolvers from "./resolvers/index.js";
import cors from "cors";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import path from "path";
import { graphqlUploadExpress } from "graphql-upload";
import pubsub from "./pubsub.cjs";

dotenv.config();

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json({ limit: "50mb" }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "50mb", extended: true }));

app.use(
  "/graphql",
  graphqlUploadExpress({ maxFileSize: 10000000, maxFiles: 10 })
);

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  playground: true,
  context: async ({ req }) => {
    const user = await getAuthUser(req);
    const { operationName, variables } = req.body;
    console.log("Operation:", operationName);
    console.log("Variables:", variables);

    console.log("User object:", user);

    if (user) {
      console.log("User role:", user.role); // For debugging
      user.isAdmin = user.role === "admin";
    }
    console.log("User object after isAdmin assignment:", user); // For debugging

    return { user, req, pubsub };
  },
  uploads: false,
  subscriptions: {
    onConnect: async (connectionParams, webSocket) => {
      console.log("Websocket connection established.");

      if (connectionParams.authToken) {
        const fakeRequest = {
          headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${connectionParams.authToken}` },
        };
        const user = await getAuthUser(fakeRequest);

        console.log(user);

        if (!user) {
          console.log("Invalid auth token!");
          return; // Allow the connection but log that the token was invalid
        }
        return { user, pubsub }; // User is authenticated
      }
      console.log("Missing auth token!");
      return; // Allow the connection but log that the token was missing
    },
  },
});

await apolloServer.start();
// apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app });

const apolloExpressMiddleware = expressMiddleware(apolloServer);

app.use("/graphql", apolloExpressMiddleware);

const httpServer = createServer(app);

httpServer.listen({ port: process.env.PORT || 4000 }, () => {
  console.log(
    `Server ready at http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || 4000}${
      apolloServer.graphqlPath
    }`
  );
  console.log(
    `Subscriptions ready at ws://localhost:${process.env.PORT || 4000}${
      apolloServer.subscriptionsPath
    }`
  );
  console.log("Server has started.");
});
```

Initially I tried with Apollo server 2 and 3. After that I upgraded to v4.
This is my client.

```
import {
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  HttpLink,
  ApolloLink,
  split,
  gql,
} from "@apollo/client";
import { setContext } from "@apollo/client/link/context";
import { onError } from "@apollo/client/link/error";
import { createUploadLink } from "apollo-upload-client";
import { getMainDefinition } from "@apollo/client/utilities";
import { WebSocketLink } from "@apollo/client/link/ws";

const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql" });
const uploadLink = createUploadLink({ uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql" });

const authLink = setContext((request, previousContext) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("authToken");
  return {
    ...previousContext,
    headers: {
      ...previousContext.headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    },
  };
});

const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation }) => {
  console.log("Operation:", operation.operationName);
  console.log("Variables:", operation.variables);

  if (graphQLErrors) {
    graphQLErrors.map(({ message, locations, path, extensions }) =>
      console.log(
        `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}, Extensions: ${JSON.stringify(
          extensions
        )}`
      )
    );
  }

  if (networkError) {
    console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
  }
});

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: `ws://localhost:4000/graphql`,
  options: {
    reconnect: true,
    connectionParams: () => {
      const token = localStorage.getItem("authToken");
      console.log("Auth Token:", token);

      return {
        authToken: token,
      };
    },
    connectionCallback: (error) => {
      console.log("WebSocket Connection Callback");
      if (error) {
        console.error("Error from connectionCallback:", error);

        if (error.message === "Invalid auth token!") {
          localStorage.removeItem("authToken");
        }
      }
    },
  },
});

const isFileUploadOperation = ({ variables }) => {
  return typeof variables.file !== "undefined";
};

const isSubscriptionOperation = ({ query }) => {
  const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
  return (
    definition.kind === "OperationDefinition" &&
    definition.operation === "subscription"
  );
};

const link = ApolloLink.from([
  errorLink,
  split(
    isSubscriptionOperation,
    wsLink,
    split(
      isFileUploadOperation,
      authLink.concat(uploadLink),
      authLink.concat(httpLink)
    )
  ),
]);

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: errorLink.concat(link),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

export default client;
```

This is an ecommerce website. I use MySQL as database and aws s3 to upload images.